# Using set_names vs. mutate(colnames) when changing data frame column names to lower case

Tags: r, dplyr, tolower

A quick question that I was looking to understand better.

**Data**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(COLUMN_1 = letters[1:3], COLUMN_2 = 1:3)

> df1
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
1        a        1
2        b        2
3        c        3
```

Why does this work in setting data frame names to lower case:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  set_names(., tolower(names(.))) 

> df2
  column_1 column_2
1        a        1
2        b        2
3        c        3
```

But this does not?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate( colnames(.) <-  tolower(colnames(.)) )

Error: Column `colnames(.) <- tolower(colnames(.))` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 2
```

Comment: I think the documentation says it clearly: "`mutate()` adds new variables and preserves existing ones". You are probably looking for `rename()`.

Comment: If I replace mutate with rename, it throws an error.  Did you mean a different syntax?

Comment: For this particular case, you need `df1 %>%
 rename_all(tolower)`.

Comment: Thanks, although I am still trying to understand why certain syntaxes don't work.  For example, if I use  df2 <- df1 %>% rename_all(tolower(.))   I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, writing the arguments out explicitly, is:

`df1 %>% rename_all(tolower)` ==
`rename_all(.tbl = df1, .funs = tolower)`

mutate operates on the data itself, not the column names, so that's why we're using rename. We use rename_all because you don't want to type out 1 = tolower(1), 2 = tolower(2), ...

What you suggested, `df2 <- df1 %>% rename_all(tolower(.))` doesn't work because then you would be trying to feed the whole `df1` into the `tolower` function, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be this `names(df) <- tolower(names(df))`